# CDI observer not yet initialized when the event is fired

Tags: events, cdi, wildfly, java-ee-7, ejb-jar.xml

I have two SLSBs:

- `BeanF`,
- `BeanO`

in two ejb-jars:

- `ModF`,
- `ModO`.

`BeanF` fires an event and `BeanO` observes it.

The first `fire(-)` operation ends with the exception (Wildfly 8.2):

> ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component BeanF for method public void BeanF.publish(ModEvent):
>   javax.ejb.EJBException: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service
>   jboss.deployment.subunit."myapp.ear"."modO.jar".component.BeanO.VIEW."BeanO".LOCAL not found

Further `fire(-)` operations reach the observer but I can't let **any** event to be lost.

Is there a way to force the initialization of the observer **before** the event is fired (or on the fly after the event is fired and awaits processing)?

The `@Observes(notifyObserver = Reception.IF_EXISTS)` only allows the event to be **skipped** silently when the observer is not ready yet.
In my case the `BeanF` cannot be dependent on `BeanO` because `ModO` must be declared after `ModF` in the `application.xml`.

Is it possible with CDI events/listeners or would I need to go with JMS?

Comment: Can you switch from SLSB to Singletons? Then using @Sturtup may do the trick?

Comment: Reception.IF_EXISTS is mostly applicable to beans with wider scope (like SessionScope , ApplicationScoped , etc). If your bean is @Stateless, the instance is "created" only for a single call and that makes IF_EXISTS almost always to return false (except in cases where the event firing and the observer are in the same stacktrace).

Comment: Tried annotating both beans with `@Singleton` and `@Startup` and received the same exception (I cannot annotate `BeanF` with `@DependsOn( BeanO )` because `ModF` does not see `ModO`).
Also tried changing `BeanO` to `@ApplicationScoped` and in this case the event could be received - the `BeanO.observe(@Observes ...)` method started executing, performed some logging but crashed with `ServiceNotFoundException` exception when tried to call some other `@Stateless` bean (this other bean must be `@Stateless` since it uses the `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW` annotation).

Answer (score 3):

#### Other experiments

Tried annotating both beans with `@Singleton` and `@Startup` and received the same exception (I cannot annotate `BeanF` with `@DependsOn( BeanO )` because `ModF` does not see `ModO`).
Also tried changing `BeanO` to `@ApplicationScoped` and in this case the event could be received - the `BeanO.observe(@Observes ...)` method started executing, performed some logging but crashed with `ServiceNotFoundException` exception when tried to call some other `@Stateless` bean (this other bean must be `@Stateless` since it uses the `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW` annotation).

#### CDI solution

A bit ugly but working solution: caching/queueing events: split `BeanO` into two beans: `BeanO1` and `BeanO2`. Let `BeanO1` be an `@ApplicationScoped` bean, let it observe the event and detect if `BeanO2` is ready by calling some hollow method and catching `ServiceNotFoundException`. If `BeanO2` is not there then the event is queued in `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` in `BeanO1`. `BeanO2` is stateless and does everything what `BeanO` was doing except observing. When an event arrives and `BeanO2` is ready then `BeanO1` first pushes events from the queue. This is acceptable only when there **will** be some other event that will actually trigger handling older events.

#### JMS

I guess that using JMS would be the cleanest solution but there also are a few pitfalls:

- if a `topic` is used then we may fall in the original problem again - the subscriber registers after the first message is sent (not sure about the spec but afair the message is lost when there are no subscribers).
- if a `queue` is used then problem may appear when `ModF` is used in some other product and there is no `ModO` - the queue will swell and this may not be super gut.

  - maybe `ModF` could define some `MDB` that reads all events drops them and `ModO` somehow registers its own `MDB` that has higher priority (just guessing, don't know if this is possible)
  - maybe `ModO` could contain a configuration text file with a queue's name so `ModF` can read that file, initialize connection to queue on the fly and put events to this queue (if there is no `ModO` and there is no file then events are not fired by `ModF`).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think that CDI creates a 'new' instance of the bean and delivers the event to it in case

- there is no active contextual instance (in current scope), and
- the observer is not conditional

I wrote about this [here](https://abhirockzz.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/integrating-cdi-and-websockets/)

So this behavior is strange IMO

In terms of alternatives - is it possible to declare you observer method as 'static' ? CDI will certainly invoke it in that case

Also, if you haven't already, I would strongly suggest reading the CDI spec doc (ch 10 and section 5.5.6)